# Analysis of Oracle Explain Plan - Oracle Doing Full Table Access

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan, sqlperformance

We have a problematic SQL and in looking at the Explain Plan there appears to be a lot of Full Table Access. From what I understand this is normal especially if the query is more on the inside of the plan versus being at the top.

Each of the tables have indexes on them and proper columns used so it is not clear why Oracle will not use the indexes. Can anyone provide high level guidance as to whether I should expect so many full table scans, or does this SQL need better optimization? We are running out of memory in Oracle often, removing the SORT does help on lowering the cost but not memory.

**SQL**

```
SELECT
     TRNLOAD.WORK_ORDER_NUMBER,
     TRNMANIFESTHDR.CUST_MANIFEST_NUMBER,
     TRNMANIFESTHDR.STATE_MANIFEST_NUMBER,
     TRNINVENTORY.MAN_PAGE_NO,
     ...snipped columns for size
     TRNINVENTORY.MAN_SYS_NUMBER,
     NVL(REFINVSPLITCODES.DOUBLE_COUNT,'N') double_count,
     MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,NVL(TRNLOAD.CHECKIN_TIME, TRNINVENTORY.GROUPED_DATE)) months,
     AESOP.DF_GETINVCOLORCODE 
        (TRNINVENTORY.INV_STATUS,
         TRNLOAD.CHECKOUT_TIME,
         DF_IS_ONSITECUST(TRNMANIFESTHDR.LOC_CODE,TRNMANIFESTHDR.BILLING_CUSTOMER))
              color_cd,
     TRNINVENTORY.CREATED_BY,
     TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.EPA_CONSENT_NUMBER 
FROM REFGENERATOR,
     TRNINVENTORY,
     TRNLOAD,
     TRNMANIFESTDETAIL,
     TRNMANIFESTHDR,
     REFWASTESTREAM,
     REFRTTAXCODES,
     REFINVENTORYSTATUS,
     REFINVSPLITCODES,
     REFHANDLINGCODES,
     reftreatmentgroup,
     TRNMANIFRETAILTRIP  trip
WHERE    (TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.LOC_CODE(+) = TRNINVENTORY.LOC_CODE)
     AND (TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.MAN_SYS_NUMBER(+) = TRNINVENTORY.MAN_SYS_NUMBER)
     AND (TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.MAN_PAGE_NUMBER(+) = TRNINVENTORY.MAN_PAGE_NO)
     AND (TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.MAN_LINE_NUMBER(+) = TRNINVENTORY.MAN_LINE_NO)
     AND (TRNMANIFESTHDR.LOC_CODE(+) = TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.LOC_CODE)
     AND (TRNMANIFESTHDR.MAN_SYS_NUMBER(+) = TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.MAN_SYS_NUMBER)
     AND (TRNMANIFESTHDR.MAN_PAGE_NO(+) = TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.USER_MANPAGE)
     AND (TRNMANIFESTHDR.LOC_CODE = TRNLOAD.LOC_CODE(+))
     AND (TRNMANIFESTHDR.WORK_ORDER_NUMBER = TRNLOAD.WORK_ORDER_NUMBER(+))
     AND (TRNMANIFESTHDR.LOC_CODE = REFGENERATOR.LOC_CODE(+))
     AND (TRNMANIFESTHDR.GEN_SYS_NUMBER = REFGENERATOR.GEN_SYS_NUMBER(+))
     AND (TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.LOC_CODE = REFWASTESTREAM.LOC_CODE(+))
     AND (TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.WASTE_STREAM_NUMBER = REFWASTESTREAM.WASTE_STREAM_NUMBER(+))
     AND (TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.PROFILE_NUMBER = REFWASTESTREAM.PROFILE_NUMBER(+))
     AND (REFHANDLINGCODES.LOC_CODE(+) = TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.LOC_CODE)
     AND (REFHANDLINGCODES.WASTE_STREAM_NUMBER(+) = TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.WASTE_STREAM_NUMBER)
     AND (REFHANDLINGCODES.PROFILE_NUMBER(+) = TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.PROFILE_NUMBER)
     AND (refhandlingcodes.loc_code = reftreatmentgroup.loc_code(+))
     AND (refhandlingcodes.tgroup = reftreatmentgroup.tgroup(+))
     AND (REFINVENTORYSTATUS.ACTION_ID = TRNINVENTORY.INV_STATUS)
     AND (trninventory.split_code = refinvsplitcodes.code(+))
     AND (trninventory.loc_code = refrttaxcodes.loc_code(+))
     AND (trninventory.inv_taxcode = REFRTTAXCODES.TAX_ID(+))
     AND ( (TRNINVENTORY.LOC_CODE = :ai_loc))
     and (trip.loc_code (+) = trninventory.loc_code)
     and (trip.inventory_no (+) = trninventory.inventroty_no)
     and (trip.split_no (+) = trninventory.split_no)
     AND NOT (NVL (TRNINVENTORY.IS_PRODUCT, 'N') = 'Y' OR NVL (REFWASTESTREAM.WASTE_TYPE, 'A') = 'D')
     AND nvl(TRNLOAD.WORK_ORDER_TYPE,'STD') = 'STD' 
ORDER BY TRNLOAD.WORK_ORDER_NUMBER,
     TRNINVENTORY.MAN_SYS_NUMBER,
     TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.USER_MANPAGE,
     DF_sort_string (TRNMANIFESTDETAIL.USER_MANLINE),
     TRNINVENTORY.INVENTROTY_NO,
     TRNINVENTORY.SPLIT_NO,
     TRNINVENTORY.GROUPED_DATE,
     TRNINVENTORY.GROUP_NO
```

**EXPLAIN PLAN**

I had to adjust this to be more narrow for readability, which is why there are some abbreviations.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation                              | Name                | Rows | Bytes| Cost |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                     |  377K|  198M|  112K|
|  1 | SORT ORDER BY                          |                     |  377K|  198M|  112K|
|  2 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                 |                     |  377K|  198M| 68645|
|  3 |   TBL ACCESS FULL                      | TRNMANIFRETAILTRIP  |  128 | 2944 |    3 |
|  4 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                |                     |  377K|  190M|68639 |
|  5 |    TBL ACCESS FULL                     | REFTREATMENTGROUP   |  101 | 1313 |    3 |
|  6 |    FILTER                              |                     |      |      |      |
|  7 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER              |                     |  377K|  186M|68633 |
|  8 |      TBL ACCESS FULL                   | REFWASTESTREAM      |  204K|   11M|  755 |
|  9 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |                     |  377K|  163M|58820 |
| 10 |       TBL ACCESS FULL                  | REFGENERATOR        | 80447| 3535K|  594 |
| 11 |       FILTER                           |                     |      |      |      |
| 12 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                     |  377K|  147M|50460 |
| 13 |         TBL ACCESS FULL                | TRNLOAD             |  507K|   16M|2920  |
| 14 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER          |                     |  376K|  135M|39501 |
| 15 |          TBL ACCESS FULL               | TRNMANIFESTHDR      |  844K|   49M| 4646 |
| 16 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER         |                     |  376K|  113M|26090 |
| 17 |           TBL ACCESS FULL              | REFHANDLINGCODES    |  183K| 4483K|  631 |
| 18 |           HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        |                     |  376K|  104M|19737 |
| 19 |            TBL ACCESS FULL             | TRNMANIFESTDETAIL   |  289K|   14M| 4496 |
| 20 |            HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER       |                     |  376K|   85M| 9890 |
| 21 |             TBL ACCESS FULL            | REFINVSPLITCODES    |   48 |  288 |    3 |
| 22 |             HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER      |                     |  376K|   83M| 9883 |
| 23 |              TBL ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | REFRTTAXCODES       |    8 |   80 |    3 |
| 24 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN         | PK_TAXCODE_LOCATION |    8 |      |    1 |
| 25 |              HASH JOIN                 |                     |  376K|   80M| 9877 |
| 26 |               INDEX FULL SCAN          | IDX_INVSTATUS_TYPE  |   22 |  176 |    1 |
| 27 |               TBL ACCESS FULL          | TRNINVENTORY        |  376K|   77M| 9873 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Every single join is an outer join? Why is that?

Comment: Good question, I suspect many of the outer joins are not needed, cannot imagine they all need to be outer joins. I'm green at this company, inherited the existing code. Like all IT shops there are things that make you wonder. I will try reducing the outer joins and see if that might be the culprit. ty

Comment: Have statistics been calculated recently?

Comment: The stats were up to date thanks for that comment. As APC noticed everything was outer joined and turns out that wasn't necessary to get the result set the business needed. Appreciated all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Can anyone provide high level guidance as to whether I should expect so many full table scans, or does this SQL need better optimization?

A: there are very few places where the data is being subset, that is the first place to look for index tuning opportunities, but I see functions applied to the column which may imply the need for a function based index.

The next place to look is the join conditions, are the join columns indexed.  Oracle can choose to ignore indexes on joined columns if it thinks full table scan is just as efficient or more efficient.

Generally, I'd say don't worry about full table scans, except, I would worry about full table scans if the following are true:

1. the performance requirements are not being met
2. the full scans are on large tables
3. the wait events for the session running the SQL show high waits on "db file scattered read" for the large object in question (i.e. full table scan)

Comment: It turns out the outer joins were the primary culprit - after removing the ones that could be removed the memory needed dropped to about 60 K versus 198 M and cost was a little under a third. Since this resolved the problem I didn't bother looking at wait events. I didn't think that the outer joins would raise memory so much, maybe CPU and Disk but guess I don't understand the internals of Oracle that well!

Comment: Outer joins will use a lot of temp tablespace and PGA memory.  If you could still meet the requirements and make it faster by eliminating them, that's great.